# C# Instagram private api GetUserTimelineFeedAsync function "Mothod not allowed"

Tags: c#, api, instagram

I am developing utility application using `c# instagram private api`.
Almost apis are working greatly but the `GetUserTimeLineFeedAsync` function returns `Method Not Allowed [405]` response.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please, share your code with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which library you are using now.
According to my experience, 405 errors are almost about the bad path problem.
So please check the api url is correct or not. 
PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THE LAST SLASH '/' OF THE API URL.